# d3 + drawing svgs + incorrectly overwriting

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

this i my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HattrickNZ/9z8yjs7z/) that shows 2 piecharts which gives me something like this in the html view:

```
<svg width="220" height="220">
<svg width="220" height="220">
```

this is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HattrickNZ/9z8yjs7z/1/) where I am trying to insert an svg before the 2 piecharts, but I am not writing it correctly, 1 of the pie charts gets over written.

Can anyone advise how I can have all 3 svgs showing?

All my code as it is in the 2nd [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HattrickNZ/9z8yjs7z/1/)

```
var width = $(document).width()-50 || 960,
    height = $(document).height()-50 ||500;

    //attaches/appends a svg tag to a body tag with a width and height
    /*  COMMENT IN */
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

    data=[[10, 5],[32, 24]]
    z = d3.scale.category20c();  

    //attaches/appends a svg tag to a body tag with a width and height
    var svg2 = d3.select("body").selectAll("svg")
        .data(data)
        .enter().append("svg:svg")
        .attr("width", 220)
        .attr("height", 220)
        .append("svg:g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + 100 + "," + 100 + ")")

    svg2.selectAll("path")
        .data(d3.layout.pie())
        .enter().append("svg:path")
        .attr("d", d3.svg.arc()
        .innerRadius(10)
        .outerRadius(100))
        .style("fill", function(d, i) { return z(i); });
```

NOTE: Some further background is that the first svg is a map that I have working. And What I am trying to do is create a layer on top of this which will be piecharts, in this case just 2, but you have to start somewhere :)

Answer (score 0):

Your interpretation of the results is slightly wrong. The first pie chart doesn't get overwritten, it won't get rendered in the first place. In the commented in version you are appending the svg for your map, which works fine and can easily be identified by the `width` and `height` values assigned to it.

When trying to append the SVGs for your pie charts, you are selecting all SVGs in the body by doing `d3.select("body").selectAll("svg")`. This selection will include the previously appended SVG. You are then binding your data to the selection which will compute the data join. Since you are binding an array of data without any key function the join will be based on the index. Thus, the existing SVG will correspond to the first element in the data array and will be put to the update selection. As your code only works on the enter selection the first pie chart will never be drawn because it doesn't belong to this selection. The second one is output as expected.

One way to work around this is to use a CSS marker class for the pie charts. That way you could limit the second selection to the SVGs having the marker class:

```
var svg2 = d3.select("body").selectAll("svg.pie")   // select with class "pie"
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", 220)
    .attr("height", 220)
    .classed("pie", true)                           // set marker class for all pie charts
    .append("svg:g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + 100 + "," + 100 + ")")
```

Because no SVG is present having class `pie`, all your data will end up in the enter selection rendering an SVG containing a pie chart for every data element as expected. I have updated your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9z8yjs7z/2/) to show the effect.

Comment: tks, my understanding is flawed, what i was hoping for is that the pies will over lap the map but i guess I want something different for that. do i need something like `<svg>` with lots of `<path d=*>` making the map part and then the pies drawn within this same svg with there own `<path d=*>` tags?